# Criteria based on User's Role and attributes

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria

I created a criteria to fetch users with a specific role(Candidate Role) and also using its username attribute. Here is the criteria that I am using:

```
    def userRoleList = UserRole.createCriteria().list(max: params.max,offset: params.offset){
        createAlias("user","u")
        addToCriteria(Restrictions.ilike("u.username",name,MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
        eq("role",Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_CANDIDATE"))
        if(userType==1){
            addToCriteria(Restrictions.eq("u.deleted",1))
        }else if(userType==2){
            addToCriteria(Restrictions.eq("u.deleted",0))
        }
    }

    def userList = userRoleList*.user
```

I am getting error `Unknown column 'u1_.username' in 'where clause'` error

Comment: I believe `ilike` is case sensitive - could it be it?

Comment: Which version of Grails?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to be creating alias or such for this.  You can also further utilise the criteria builder DSL to specify the restrictions.  For example,

```
def userList = UserRole.createCriteria().list(max: params.max,offset: params.offset){
  eq("role",Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_CANDIDATE"))
  user {
    ilike('username','%' + name + '%')
    if (userType == 1){
        eq("deleted", 1)
    } else if(userType == 2){
        eq("deleted", 0)
    }
  }
}*.user
```

The above appears to fall victim to a bug/feature of either Grails or Hibernate that causes failure if the table in question uses a composite key..  as UserRole (from the SpringSecurity plug) does.

An alternative is to use HQL - the equivalent of the above could be written as

```
def userList = UserRole.executeQuery("select user from UserRole " +
            "where role_id = ? " +
            "and lower(username) like ? " +
            "and deleted = ?",[Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_CANDIDATE")?.id,
                               "%" + name.toLowerCase() + "%",
                               userType == 1 ? 1 : 0])
```

The first parameter to executeQuery is the query statement, the second parameter is a map containing the parameters to use in the query.

Comment: Getting MissingMethodException. No signature of method: com.assesmart.user.User.call() is applicable for argument types: (com.assesmart.user.UserController$_index_closure1_closure11) on the "user {"  line.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the static methods on `Restrictions` that return expression instances which aren't used anywhere.

Invoke the instance methods (omit `Restrictions.`) so that they take effect in the `Criteria` being built.

Comment: I tried createAlias("user","u"); ilike("u.username", name); but it is giving NPE  in the createCriteria() line. I also tried addToCriteria(Restric..) but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Is passed in `name` null?

Comment: No, it is either blank("") or contains some value.

Comment: Ok. I am actually getting Unknown column 'u1_.username' in 'where clause' error.